# Create systemd top-level drop-in

Tags: nixos

Systemd supports top-level drop-ins which can be applied to all systemd services or units of a particular type. This is super useful if you want to, for example, have an email sent anytime a systemd service enters a failure state.

Essentially, you have to create a file at `/etc/systemd/system/service.d/onfailure.conf` and the contents of that file will get applied as a drop-in to *all* systemd services.

Here's a detailed explanation for how this works in systemd:
https://trstringer.com/systemd-top-level-drop-in/

How would I go about doing this in NixOS?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a direct answer to this problem over on the NixOS discourse forums:

https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-use-toplevel-overrides-for-systemd/12501

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).